# Как параллельно запускать один и тот же скрипт?

Tags: node.js

У меня есть nodejs скрипт, app.js

Его содержание такое:

```
(async () => {
     .... тут весь код скрипта ....
})();
```

Сейчас я запускаю его через командную строку `node app parametr1 parametr2`

Мне же нужно запускать выполнение этого скрипта (с разными входными параметрами) параллельно сразу неограниченное количество раз.

Как это можно организовать? Учитывая что скрипт планируется размещать на виртуальном vds ubuntu.

Буду благодарен за помощь!

Comment: Ваш **node app** это приложение, которое постоянно работает или просто скрипт, который выполняется и завершается?

Comment: @SwaD просто скрипт который выполняется и завершается

Comment: Добавьте метку вашей ОС. Дополните вопрос, по какому событию вы хотите запускать скрипт. По сути, тут nodejs будет отрабатывать как обычный скрипт. Запустите из консоли 50 раз, будет создано 50 процессов, далее вопросы к самой ОС, как она будет это отрабатывать.

Comment: @SwaD дело в том что я не знаю как организовать такой запуск скрипта (событие). например, можно было бы установить pm2 и экспресс сервер, и запускать скрипт обращением по url. но скрипт может выполнятся около 10 минут, поэтому я думаю такое решение не совсем подходит...